# Adaptar height de dos elementos hijos de un flexbox a igual

Tags: html, css, responsive, flexbox

El problema es que tengo es que es estoy intentando hacer mi página responsive y quiero que  dos elementos hijos de mi flexbox principal tengan la misma altura aunque su contenido no la ocupe completamente. También quiero que al disminuir/aumentar el tamaño de la página la relación de altura se mantenga. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1545px){
.sidebar{   
    float: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row ;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;

  }

.redes{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 30%;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}

<div class="sidebar">
            <div class="redes"><h3>JOIN OUR DISCORD SERVER</h3>  
            Chat with the community, share your opinion and contribute to the game's development. <br>
            <a href="#">
            <img class="press" src="zzzz.png"> 
            </a>
            </div>

            <div class="redes">
            <h3>BECOME A BETA TESTER</h3>
             Our game is still in development, which means that
 we're open to any kind of opinion or contribution.
 </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si aún no solucionaste, aquí está una opción.

Hize algunos cambios pequeños para que puedas entender cómo acomodar los hijos según tu pregunta.
Te recomiendo estudiar más sobre Flex box.

Para acomodarlos hijos, el padre `.sidebar` debe tener un alto fijo en **`px`**, **`em`** ó **`rem`**. Pero no en porcentaje, porque no funcionará para lo que quieres, porque el hijo depende del padre para su altura o anchura. Y si el padre es incierto, el hijo también.

También le puse un `padding: 30px`, para simplificar el código, y no definir un `margin: 30px` al hijo.

Ahora a los hijos `.redes` le definir un `margin: auto` con un `width` menor a 50% para que haya un margen entre ambos y que no se peguen.

Por último, analiza bien y prueba adaptando a tu estilo mejorando a tu gusto. Esto es una base de ejemplo de extenza riqueza de CSS y diseño web.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1545px) {
 
 
 .sidebar { 
  float: none; 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: row; 
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20em; /* altura importante en px, em ó rem (NO %) */ 
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 30px; /* para no poner margenes fijo a hijos */
  background-color: lightgreen;
 } 
 
 .redes { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column; 
  
  /* el width puede ser fijo: por ej.: 10em (responsive) */ 
  width: 45%; /* para que haya un margen entre ambos lados */
  height: 100%; /* altura total (pero con el padre de altura definido) */
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px; /* para mejorar */
  background-color: red;
 }
 
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"> 
   
   <div class="redes">
<h3>JOIN OUR DISCORD SERVER</h3> Chat with the community, share your opinion and contribute to the game's development. 
<br> 
<a href="#"> 
 <img class="press" src="zzzz.png"> 
</a>
   </div> 
   
   <div class="redes"> 
<h3>BECOME A BETA TESTER</h3> Our game is still in development, which means that we're open to any kind of opinion or contribution. 
   </div> 
  
  </div>
```

Comment: No olvides marcar la respuesta como aceptada ✓ si te ha solucionado. Esto para que sirva a otros que necesiten.